# Prevent webpage dialog from spawning new browser window?

Tags: javascript, showmodaldialog

I have an open web page dialog.  From there, what I'd like to do is when the user clicks on a link, refresh the contents of the dialog with modified query string parameters.  The problem I am running into is that rather than refresh the same web page with new parameters, a new browser window pops up.

Here is the page used to open the dialog:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowPopup() {
        var popWinFeatures = "dialogWidth: 800px;dialogHeight:600px;center:yes;status:no;scroll:no;resizable:yes;help:no";

        window.showModalDialog("webPageDialog.html","PopUpWin",popWinFeatures);

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="openWebPageDialog" onclick="ShowPopup()">Click For Modal</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the code within the webpage dialog that attempts to refresh the webpage with changed query string parameters:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var queryString = "?ab=123";
        var newURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname;

        $('#testLink').attr('href', newURL+queryString);
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="" id="testLink" target="_self">Please Click Me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I've also tried using `window.open` as well as setting `window.location`.  And I've also tried setting `window.location.href` but the result was the same.

the new browser window displays exactly what I expect.  It's just not in the same window.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Since posting this question, I came up with two possible solutions.  In case anyone comes after me and wants to know what I ended up doing, here you go!

The first was just to make the popup non-modal.  Removing the modal piece gave me the behavior exactly like I expected it.  This didn't work in my situation however for a different reason...  It seems that the session cookie was not carried over which in this web app, would cause the log-in page to be displayed before then displaying the correct page.  This struck me as odd, but ran out of time to investigate why that was happening.

Second (and this is the solution i ended up going with) was to use an iframe, and display what i needed within the iframe.  Definitely not my favorite, but it works!